# Is it possible to use JSON format input for BERT model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cluster-analysis

I am trying to create one knowledge base (single source of truth) gathered from multiple web sources. (ex. wiki <-> fandom)

So I want to try a Siamese network or calculate cosine similarity with BERT embedded documents.

Then, can I ignore those json structures and train them anyway?

Comment: BERT is a language representation model that requires textual data as input. You would have to extract text from your JSON or dump and convert it to plain text.

Comment: @SVPraveen I narrowed the question down into json format. Then would there be any efficient way to extract text from json without losing key value dependency? Different database have different names for same key (eg. origin vs source vs genesis) and some are not 1-1 mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although BERT wasn't specifically trained to find similarity between JSON data, you could always extract and concatenate the values of your JSON into a long sentence and leave it to BERT to capture the context as you expect.

Alternatively, you could generate a cosine similarity score for each key-value dependency between the JSONs and aggregate them to generate a net similarity score for the JSON data pair.

Also, see [Sentence-BERT (SBERT)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084), a modification of the pre-trained BERT network that use siamese and triplet network structures to derive semantically meaningful sentence embeddings that can be compared using cosine-similarity.